# DRF: Best way to supply a dynamic default field value?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, default

Our SAAS site utilizes a DRF backend with a Vue frontend.  We have fields that do not require a value from the user, but do require a value in the database.  I'd like to know where's the best place to supply such dynamic defaults.  I've read in other posts that "save() is not always called" - though I don't yet know the circumstances where it would not be called.

So, consider the following model:

```py
class Tenant(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subdomain = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    schema_name = models.CharField(max_length=63, unique=True)
```

In this case, only "name" is required (from the user); "schema_name", if left blank in the frontend form, can be derived from "name" (converting it to lowercase).  Likewise, "subdomain" can be derived from "schema_name".  "subdomain" can be blank/null because the "public" schema doesn't reference a subdomain, but its value will be required for all tenants other than "public".)

So where should I put the code that populates those fields if they are blank when it comes time to create or update a Tenant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save will be called unless you do bulk updates, so you can put it there just fine.  I prefer not to if there is a choice, but sometimes there isn't.

If you want to put it in the serializer, you can write something like this, and then use a [`ModelViewSet`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) to handle the details:

```
class TenantSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    name = CharField(required=True, min_length=1)
    sub_domain = CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Tenant
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'sub_domain']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        # attrs is all fields parsed & validated on a per-field level
        # in here you can do validation that depends on >1 field
        # values returned will be passed to the serializer create()/update()
        # via the common serializer.save() method
        if self.instance:
            # doing an update, maybe different logic, or just ignore?
        else:
            if not attrs.get('sub_domain'): # missing or blank
                attrs['sub_domain'] = parse_subdomain(attrs.get('name'))
        return attrs
```

Comment: Why do you "prefer not to if there is a choice"?  And what are the choices, other than in the serializer as you showed in your answer?

Comment: Its just a preference, I do have 'save' logic in a few cases but... with the serialier doing all sorts of work I find it gets confusing, since there is a lot of logic in many serializers.  One other way to do this that I also use on models that are modified for multiple places is `signals`, usually on `pre_save`.  The worst is having 2 places that *both* do complicated logic and the try to figure out the interactions.  Favor "least suprise" and what you see is what you get.   You can also override the `create` method on the `ModelManager` associated with `MyModel.objects`